# How do I get return object properties from an AJAX-enabled WCF service (ASP.Net)?

Tags: ajax, wcf, json

I have created an AJAX-enabled WCF service to return a List<> of a custom class I created. I can get it to return data, but I have no idea how to access the property values of my class.

Here's my class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Favorite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
    public List<Favorite> GetFavorites()
    {
        MembershipUser thisUser = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        int userId = (int)thisUser.ProviderUserKey;
        return GetFavorites(userId);
    }
```

Here's the configuration for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MySvc">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MySvcEndpointBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MySvc" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MySvcEndpointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And here is the jQuery script where I actually call the service:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MySvc.svc/GetFavorites",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var favs = result.d;
    }
});
```

In my javascript, I can call "favs.length", and it gives me the right number of results. But if I try, for instance, to access "favs[0].Title", I get a message of "undefined". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see the contents?

Comment: Yes, I used Chrome to step through my javascript, and I can see the object properties and their values in the debugger, but I do not know how to access the values programmatically.

Comment: What are the names of the properties? I mean, if you can see `favs[0]` and if you can see that `favs[0]` has a `title` property, then of course, use `favs[0].title`. `var fav = favs[0];` and then look at `fav`.

Comment: Same problem, when I try to get favs[0].Title or fav.Title, I still get a message of "undefined". It's frustrating, because I can see the properties and their values in the debugger, but can't figure out how to actually use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the console.

```
success: function (result) {

// log
console.log(result);

// dir
console.dir(result);

// iterating through an object's properties in JS

for(var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++){
    for(property in favs[i]){
        console.log(property + ": " + favs[i][property]);
    }
}

};
```

Comment: It's weird, it's almost like it's trying to say that my "Title" property is actually called "<Title>k__BackingField".

Comment: Try to use [DataContract] instead of [Serializable]

Also, add [DataMember] for each property

i.e. 

[DataMember]
public string Title { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks Omar, as soon as I used DataContract/DataMember instead of Serializable, it started working as expected.